# Access database is not a valid path

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have build a VB project to a setup installer and I have Access database in it. I have already attached the access file in my setup. However, when i try to install my project to other computer to let other users use, this happens:

[image]

Sorry for the red-coloured sketch. It is my Laptop's name.
How to solve this problem, anyone?

I have search some solutions,
some say to change to UNC path. Some say to use linked table manager.
But I cannot use linked table manager as I imported my Excel file to Access.

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q30kX.png

EDIT: I have placed the Access Database file in my setup installer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the **connection string**. It has an *absolute* path looking in your `Documents` folder. You should add the database to the solution in Visual Studio, set the installer to deploy the database file o the `AppData` folder, and change the connection string to look in that path.

Comment: I have added the database to the solution in Visual Studio already. Where can I find AppData folder?

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing said error because your db. file path is not valid in the client unit. 
Perform the following

1. Change the location of your access database. Place it next to the
   `.exe` of your Solution
2. Depending on how you set up your connection to the database, change the `connection string` to simply the name of your access file (ie : `C:\Users\asasdas\orsa.accdb` to simply `orsa.accdb`

Comment: Change the location of your access database?
Where should I locate my access database file?

Comment: I have simply changed to orsa.accdb.
However, the database is not displayed in my datagridview.

Comment: I meant what I said. Go to your Access (.accdb) file and place ON THE SAME FOLDER with your application (.exe) .

Comment: Can this way functions when I want to place my project together with Access Database to other computers?

Comment: Yes, it should work. For a much more clean approach try Joel Coolhorns answer on placing it on `AppData` as well.
Also, if the solution works, don't forget to upvote answers that have helped you and accept one that worked for you.

Comment: But actually, I have pasted my Access Database on the same folder with EXE file. But it doesnt work. The EXE file means the installer before we setup or after we have installed i? is it the shortcut one?

Comment: ..the .exe we are talking about is the one after your installer has been installed. Again if this answers your question, do not forget to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Your program try to access a database on the current disk where the program is installed. But this path doesn't exists. You should try to provide a dynamic file path? Or you can also add your database to the embedded ressources and then pick out it from the ressources to an existing folder (the assembly executing path for exemple).

Answer (score 0):

**if you are not using connection class** 
 `Dim provider As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data    source=|DataDirectory|"
    Dim database As String = "orsa.accdb"
    Dim connstring As String = provider & database`

put your database in to bin directry in your application and then recreate exe